# Прервать http-запрос

Tags: php, javascript

Подскажите, есть ли возможность самостоятельно прервать в браузере активный http-запрос?

Пример: по клику ajax-ом подгружаю в блок трансляцию с веб-камеры в формате MJPEG.

Трансляция идет, все норм. Но при подгрузке следующей трансляции, предыдущяя по прежнему работает, нагружая сервер своими пакетами.

На данный момент, единственное найденное решение - это обновлять страницу. 
Буду признателен за ответ, если существует инной способ прерывания

p.s. Для подгрузки трансляции использую Fancybox

```
<a data-fancybox data-type="ajax" data-src="/camera?number=1" href="javascript:;">камера 1</a>
```

Comment: Показывайте код. Без кода помочь невозможно.

Comment: Вы через АПИ проигрываете (есть два способа, через апи, и через html-теги, то о чем идет речь кажется только через апи можно). Разве у АПИ нету stop метода, или что-то такого?

Comment: Увы, организация, на сервере которой крутяться камеры, использует стороннее приложение для веб-камер, в котором нет такой функции :(

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/abort

Comment: @Santasflow нет, это не то. В браузере не так много способов проиграть видео. И способ через АПИ браузера (не организации) позволяет делать стоп.

Comment: @carcinogen75 уверен, что ваш совет не поможет в данном случае.